# how could access actuator endpoints in non-web application

Tags: spring-boot

This is not a web project, but I still add `spring-boot-starter-actuator` in pom, and specify `management.port=8081`, then in last of run method of `CommandLineRunner` , have below code,

```
System.in.read();
```

when started this project, it will hold on. Then I will to access `http://localhost:8081/configprops`, but show below message:

```
This webpage is not available
```

So how could access actuator endpoints in non-web application?
BTW why I want to do so, because when started my project it can't load yml data successfully and caused NPE. So I want to access `/configprops` to check it.

My yml like this:

```
spring:
    profiles.active: default

---

spring:
    profiles: default

user: 
   foo: 
      aaa: aaa@foo.com
---

spring:
   profiles: test        

user: 
   foo: 
       aaa: aaa@foo.com
       bbb: bbb@foo.com

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="user", locations="user.yml")
public class UserConfig {
    private HashMap<String, String> foo;    
}
```

Comment: You can use the actuator even with non-web applications. I have many CommandLineRunner based Spring Boot applications that only start an embedded Tomcat for serving the actuator endpoints

Comment: @Marged Could you explain how do you start an embedded Tomcat from CommandLineRunner to serve the /health endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a non web application you can access the Actuator endpoints with JMX. Use JConsole or JVisualVM to read the MBeans. See the Spring Boot documentation for more details: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-jmx

Comment: thanks! but in non-web project, you still have to let process hold on by some method e.g. `Thread.sleep()` or `System.in.read()`

Comment: In addition query it by jmx, does exist any other manner , e.g `System.getProperty("user.foo")` that is could output it programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @dunni in jconsole MBeans tab you could see

[image]

when click getData I got a list , one line told me

```
userConfig={prefix=user, properties={foo=null}}
```