# Spring CommandLineRunner with actuator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

I would like to create console application (**WebApplicationType.NONE**). Then I implement a CommandLineRunner interface etc. Let's assume it's a job that run periodically.

But also I would like to have actuator endpoints, because I would like to expose metrics for prometheus. Is that possible ? I have the dependency, but spring does not expose these endpoints if the WebApplicationType equals to NONE.

How to deal with that problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how could access actuator endpoints in non-web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546884/how-could-access-actuator-endpoints-in-non-web-application)

Comment: Yea, it does, thank you.